# myetherwallet & speed

Tags: myetherwallet

I am trying to send ETH from MEW but nothing showing even in etherscan. I submitted three times now. I assume the network somehow is overloaded.

What should I do in terms of gas limits etc?

I sent from an exchange without issues. So I guess ETH is working OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try increasing the **gas price** so that it will get mined quicker. If you have **Tx hash**, then put that in **Check Tx Status** instead of checking in etherscan directly as you may get additional details on your transactions, see below:
[image]

Thank you!!!

Comment: Is there a recommendation for the GWEI? I just saw it is very broad - from 1 to 120.

Comment: if you see on etherscan the gas used per block is currently around 68 GWEI (https://etherscan.io/blocks), so recommend you to have gas price at 70GWEI.

Comment: Yes that worked - I changed to 70 or 80 GWEI and it completed in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of new users, increased interest, CryptoKitties, and misc. ICOs have created quite a mess of the TX pool and has a lot of TXs pending and taking longer than normal to send. This is a network issue and affecting all exchanges and clients.

There is simply not enough space in the blocks for the miners to mine all the transactions, and most systems are not currently set up to monitor the massive quantity of transaction requests. This is affecting all people's ability to send transactions, including our own.

#### Helpful Tools and Resources

- [See all the transactions that are pending here](https://etherscan.io/txsPending)
- [See current gas prices and network information here](https://ethgasstation.info/)

#### What is Gas

Ethereum is the network, also known as the blockchain. Ether (ETH) is the fuel for that network. When you send tokens, interact with a contract, send ETH, or do anything else on the blockchain, you must pay for that computation. That payment is calculated in `Gas` and gas is paid in `ETH`.

You are paying for the *computation*, regardless of whether your transaction succeeds or fails. Even if it fails, the miners must validate and execute your transaction *(compute)* and therefore you must pay for that computation just like you would pay for a successful transaction.

You can see your TX fee (`gas limit` * `gas price`) in ETH & USD when you search for your transaction on [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9f5080adb96fc251fb87387ec4a1f77506cb59e14ef1d87d3a018a0cd41a9eeb). This is not a TX  fee that MyEtherWallet, or any other service provider, receives. This fee is paid to miners for mining transactions, putting them into blocks, and securing the blockchain.

**When you hear `gas`, the person is either talking about:**

- Gas Limit
- Gas Price

The total cost of a transaction (the "TX fee") is the `Gas Limit` * `Gas Price`.

Typically, if someone just says "Gas", they are talking about the "Gas Limit".

You can think of the `gas limit` like the amount of liters/gallons/units of gas for a car. You can think of the `gas price` as the cost of that liter/gallon/unit of gas.

- With a car, it's `$2.50 (price)` per `gallon (unit)`.
- With Ethereum, it's `20 GWEI (price)` per `gas (unit)`.

To fill up your "tank", it takes...
- `10 gallons` at `$2.50` = `$25`
- `21000 units of gas` at `20 GWEI` = `0.00042 ETH`.

Therefore, the total TX fee will be 0.00042 Ether.

Sending tokens will typically take `~50000` gas to `~100000` gas, so the total TX fee increases to `0.001 ETH - 0.002 ETH`.

[You can use our tool to calculate GWEI <-> WEI <-> USD here](https://www.myetherwallet.com/helpers.html), which can be helpful when you want to know your TX fee in ETH, rather than GWEI.

#### Gas Limit

The `gas limit` is called the limit because it's the maximum amount of units of gas you are willing to spend on a transaction. This avoids situations where there is an error somewhere in the contract, and you spend 1 ETH....10 ETH....1000 ETH..... going in circles but arriving no where.

*21000 is the gas limit for standard transactions

#### Gas Price

If you want to spend less on a transaction, you can do so by lowering the amount you pay per unit of gas. The price you pay for each unit increases or decreases how quickly your transaction will be mined.

#### Replace a **pending TX** that you sent with too low gas

- [See what the **optimal gas price** is here (at 12/07/2017 @ 12:00am PT it was **61** GWEI)](https://ethgasstation.info/)
- [Learn about **Nonce** and how it controls which transactions are mined, or not mined](https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/transactions/what-is-nonce.html)

#### Other Tips

- Try switching the network in the upper left to use a different node. There are 4 nodes that allow you to interact with ETH: MyEtherWallet, Etherscan, Infura, and Giveth. If one is not working, simply choose another one.
- If you get a transaction hash for your transaction but it isn't showing up on Etherscan, you can check & replace the transaction with one with a higher gas price here: https://www.myetherwallet.com/#check-tx-status
- If you sent **FROM an exchange**, your best bet is to just be patient. I know we received over 1000 messages in the past 24 hours, I can't imagine what an exchange's inbox looks like right now. :(
- There are additional issues created by this increased traffic that result in unclear error messages on MyEtherWallet. We're sorry for this, and working on improving those messages. If you get an error, try pressing the generate button again, or changing the network via the dropdown in the top-right. However, be careful that you don't actually send the same transaction twice. If it says "transaction hash already imported" or "same nonce", you MAY have already sent that transaction and it's waiting to be mined. If both transactions get mined, you will send twice as much as you mean to.